# How can I add urn to SoapClient on PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, namespaces, wsdl

I have this xml generated by SoapUI from [this wsdl](https://mws2.safetypay.com/sandbox/express/ws/v.2.4/MerchantWS.asmx?wsdl):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:safetypay:mws:api:messages">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:CommunicationTestRequest>
         <urn:ApiKey>?</urn:ApiKey>
         <urn:RequestDateTime>?</urn:RequestDateTime>
         <urn:Signature>?</urn:Signature>
      </urn:CommunicationTestRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It Works ok, but when I create it with the client for PHP, SoapClient, it fails... I have found that the error its because it is slightly different, it is only missing the urn (which I have no idea what it is). The xml from SoapClient looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <CommunicationTestRequest>
            <RequestDateTime>2012-04-17T23:21:54</RequestDateTime>
            <ApiKey>XXXXX</ApiKey>
            <Signature>XXXXX</Signature>
        </CommunicationTestRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The three main diferences are:
1) In the definition the code generated by SoapClient is lacking of this:
xmlns:urn="urn:safetypay:mws:api:messages"
2) In the xml generated by SoapUI I have soapenv, while in the one generated by SoapClient it is SOAP-ENV
3) In the SoapUI's I have urn before each child, the SoapClient's not.

I've spend almost the whole day changing configurations and moving backward from objects to array (since in the past it works with other wsdl's), and my research on the internet didn't gave me nothing... so... can anyone have any idea of what's my mistake?

The request is this:

```
$std = new RequestDateTime();
$std->RequestDateTime = date ( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s', time () );
$std->ApiKey = SafetyPaySoap::API_KEY_SAND;
$std->Signature = SafetyPaySoap::SIG_KEY_SAND;
$this->_wsdl->CommunicationTest($std);
```

where the configuration for the SoapClient is this one

```
$config = array ();
$config ['exceptions'] = true;
$config ['trace'] = true;
$config ['cache_wsdl'] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE;
$config ['soap_version'] = SOAP_1_1;
parent::SoapClient ( $url . '?wsdl', $config );
```

**Edit:**
I was able to fix this error. I had to rewrite the __doRequest method. And it now looks like this:

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = null) {
    $request = str_ireplace("<{$this->_method}Request>", "<{$this->_method}Request xmlns='urn:safetypay:mws:api:messages'>", $request);
    return parent::__doRequest ( $request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way );
}
```

So, what I'm doing is add the namespace at the request, and with that it generates this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <CommunicationTestRequest xmlns='urn:safetypay:mws:api:messages'>
            <ApiKey>XXXX</ApiKey>
            <RequestDateTime>2012-04-18T20:22:51</RequestDateTime>
            <Signature>XXXXX</Signature>
        </CommunicationTestRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

The urn: is actually a XML namespace. Looking at the documentation for SoapClient, it looks like it passes in the target namespace as a 'uri' entry in the configuration array. It might be worth trying the below and seeing if that makes a difference.

```
$config = array();
$config['uri'] = "urn:safetypay:mws:api:messages";
// your other configurations
parent::SoapClient('https://mws2.safetypay.com/sandbox/express/ws/v.2.4/MerchantWS.asmx?wsdl', $config);
```